# GCP Cloud run not deploying built (minified) node js application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-run

I am using below commands to deploy my react on node.js application  to cloud run

```
gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/projectname/myapp-ui

gcloud run deploy myapp--image gcr.io/projectname/myapp-ui --platform managed --region asia-southeast1
```

It *is* deploying fine, but it is not deploying the minified JS from `build\` dir

Instead, it is deploying the the source code from `src\` with all the raw .js files.

How do I force gcloud to deploy the build dir (I have verified the `build\` dir does have the built,minified js code)?

 What am I missing?

Here is my dockerfile

```
# build environment
FROM node:18-alpine as react-build
WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./
RUN yarn
RUN yarn build

# server environment
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/configfile.template
ENV PORT 8080
ENV HOST 0.0.0.0
RUN sh -c "envsubst '\$PORT'  < /etc/nginx/conf.d/configfile.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"
COPY --from=react-build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.16",
    "@mui/material": "^5.13.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "firebase": "^10.0.0",
    "lightweight-charts": "^4.0.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-gtm-module": "^2.0.11",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-spring": "^9.7.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.11"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Dockerfile currently copies the contents of the build directory into the nginx image. However, the working directory isn't being set accordingly. Consequently, when nginx is executed, it still searches for files within the src directory.

To resolve this issue, you can try modifying the `COPY` command within your Dockerfile as follows:

```
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html   # Define the working directory
COPY --from=react-build /app/build .   # Transfer the build files into the designated working directory
```

By implementing this change, the build directory will be duplicated into the nginx image, and the designated working directory will be established.

Once you've successfully executed these modifications, you can proceed to redeploy your application. As a result, your application will correctly utilize the minified JS files located within the build directory.

Steps in detail:

1. Revise the COPY command within your Dockerfile to:

```
COPY --from=react-build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html:WORKDIR
```

2. Rebuild your Docker image once again.
3. Initiate the deployment of your application to Cloud Run.